# expand on a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I am trying to expand on a MySQL query that is already working

I have the following tables in my db... 1. Incall - a list of calls per day exported from the pbx 2. Extension – a list of extension number and associated names 3. Globalareascodes – a list of telephone country code, area code and zone number 4. Zone - a zone number that will be used to connect the cost of the call

This query works

```
SELECT 
  i.month,
  i.day,
  i.time,
  i.hrs,
  i.mins,
  i.sec,
  i.callingparty,
  i.leaddigit,
  i.calledno,
  i.calltype,
  i.calledparty,
  i.transferext,
  i.trunk,
  i.year,
  i.call_ID,
  i.active,
  i.property_id,
  i.insertdate,
  e.first,
  e.last,
  g.acode,
  g.zone,
  g.area,
  z.zone,
  z.day,
  z.evening,
  z.weekend
  FROM `incall` i LEFT JOIN `extension` e ON   i.callingparty = e.extension
  JOIN `globalareascodes` g ON i.calledno = g.acode
  JOIN `zone` z ON g.zone = z.zone
  WHERE i.`day` = '19' AND calledno = '08443'
  ORDER BY `call_ID`;
```

and gives the following results month day time hrs mins sec callingparty leaddigit calledno calltype calledparty transferext trunk year call_ID active property_id insertdate first last acode zone area zone day evening weekend 5 19 12:29 00 00 59 660 \N 08443 A \N \N 0 \N 314 0 1 2015-05-19 12:29:14 John Smith 08443 5 0845 5 0.50 0.50 0.50

I am trying get expand the query so that I can match the number called with the area / country called, I think the query needs to match the first 3 to 5 numbers of i.calledno with g.acode but cant get it working

my updated query is below, what do you think?

```
"SELECT 
i.month,
i.day,
i.time,
i.hrs,
i.mins,
i.sec,
i.callingparty,
i.leaddigit,
i.calledno,
i.calltype,
i.calledparty,
i.transferext,
i.trunk,
i.year,
i.call_ID,
i.active,
i.property_id,
i.insertdate,
e.first,
e.last,
g.acode,
g.zone,
g.area,
z.zone,
z.day,
z.evening,
z.weekend
FROM `incall` i LEFT JOIN `extension` e ON   i.callingparty = e.extension
JOIN `globalareascodes` g ON i.calledno = g.acode REGEXP '()'
LEFT JOIN `zone` z ON g.zone = z.zone
WHERE `property_id` ='%d' AND DATE(insertdate)='%s'
ORDER BY `call_ID`", $_SESSION['property'],$_GET['selectedDate'])
```

Comment: Think about what? Post your output and show where are you having problem.

Comment: What do I think? The first thing I'm thinking is: why are we writing code that is **vulnerable** to **SQL Injection** by incorporating potentially unsafe values into the text of a SQL statement? And the addition of `REGEXP '()'` doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: WHERE `property_id` ='DROP USER 'jeffrey'@'verizon.net';' AND DATE(insertdate)='select * from mysql.user'  .... gonna wreak havoc ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use REGEXP to find a partial match, you first need to ensure that the values you are using on the right side don't contain unintentional "special" characters... characters that regular expressions see as having special meaning in some contexts, e.g. `.` (dot) matching any character, `.*` (dot star) matching zero one or more characters, parens, backslashes, square brackets, etc.

An easier way to find a match on leading characters might be to use a `LIKE` comparison. You can use a `%` (percent sign) wildcard to match zero, one or more characters, and a `_` (underscore) to match exactly one character. So, the list of "special characters" you need to be concerned about is a lot less than in a regular expression.

For example:

```
  AND i.calledno LIKE CONCAT(g.acode,'%')
```

As a demonstration of how this works, we can return that expression in the SELECT list:

```
SELECT i.calledno
     , g.acode
     , i.calledno LIKE CONCAT(g.acode,'%') AS `match`
  FROM ( SELECT '1234567' AS calledno UNION ALL
         SELECT '12345' UNION ALL
         SELECT '123'
       ) i
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT '123'   AS acode UNION ALL
         SELECT '1234'  UNION ALL
         SELECT '12345' UNION ALL
         SELECT '345'   
       ) g
 ORDER BY i.calledno, g.acode
```

In the return, note that `match` column value of `1` indicates TRUE (it was a match), a column value of `0` indicates FALSE (no match).

```
calledno  acode   match  
--------  ------  -----
123       123         1
123       12345       0
123       345         0
12345     123         1
12345     12345       1
12345     345         0
1234567   123         1
1234567   12345       1
1234567   345         0
```

Note that if there are any "overlapping" values of `acode`, we can get a match to multiple rows. For example, some of the values of `calledno` matched `acode` values of both `123` and `12345`.

In a join operation, that means we'd be returning multiple rows from `i`.

If there are no overlapping values of `acode`, then it's not a problem.

---

If there are overlapping values, and we only want to return the row with  "longest" value of `acode` (and exclude any rows that matched an `acode` that is is shorter), the query would be more involved.